# Facing issue in java intellij like while clicking on debug some error is showing how to resolve it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While clicking on debug

No plugins found for prefix jetty in the current project and in the plugin groups.

To see all full stack trace of errors , re-run maven with the -e switch.

Re-run maven with -x switch to enable full debug logging.

Disconnected from the target VM , addresses : 127.0.0.1: 57179 , transport: socket.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It's some urgency can any one plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jetty server in your project configurations. And, you have to provide the path to where jetty is stored/downloaded.

Comment: Can plz share the code and can u plz suggest me how to do

Comment: Can anyone suggest me

Comment: Please see the related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991185/no-plugin-found-for-prefix-jetty-in-the-current-project-and-in-the-plugin-grou

Comment: Issue not resolved

Comment: Still facing the isuue

Comment: Can anyone plz sugget me

Comment: Still facing issue